# Does viewDidDisappear gets called when a view is presented modally

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am working on a code where I need to present a view controller in a modal style. The problem I am facing is that  when the view is presented, the previous view's viewDidDisappear gets called which results in deallocation of some properties which I'll need. What can I do so that  the viewDidDisappear does not get called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a flag for fixing this issue.

1. In the `viewWillAppear` method set the flag to true
2. When you are presenting the modal view set the flag to false
3. In the `viewDidDisappear` check whether the flag is true, if yes release the resources

Like:

Declare flag like:

```
BOOL flag;
```

Implement the method like:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   flag = true;
}


- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
   if (flag)
   {
      //release resources
   }
}


- (IBAction)showModal:(id)sender
{
   //Assuming you are using such a method to display the modal view
   flag = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cann't to do this. Because when you have pushed or present view controllers which lead to call viewDidDisappear. You can do one thing. During view will disappear call , block your function by `set flag` after presentation and `reset flag` before dismiss.